# Python Web Scraping Special Character Extract Data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
cityURL='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elko,_Nevada'

def createObj(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    return bsObj

bsObj1 = createObj(cityURL)

table1 = bsObj1.find("table", {"class":"infobox geography vcard"})
incorporated = table1.find("th", text='Incorporated (city)').findNext('td').get_text()

table1.find("th", text='. Total') # Problem here, due to the special dot, I cannot identify the "th"
```

I hope to get the following data:

Total,17.6 
 Land,17.6 
 Water,0.0

Comment: Do accept the answer if it worked for you as that may help others too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**.**" on the page is not a "**dot**". It is a unicode character **BULLET**(\u2022).

You can use python's regex(re) module to achieve this.

The updated code will look something like this :

```
import re
cityURL='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elko,_Nevada'

def createObj(url):
    html = urlopen(url)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    return bsObj

bsObj1 = createObj(cityURL)

table1 = bsObj1.find("table", {"class":"infobox geography vcard"})
incorporated = table1.find("th", text='Incorporated (city)').findNext('td').get_text()

pattern = re.compile(r'Total')
table1.find("th", text=pattern)
```

Alternatively, you can use lxml module which is lot faster than beautifulsoup.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

cityURL='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elko,_Nevada'
r = requests.get(cityURL)
root = html.fromstring(r.content)

def normalize(text) : 
    return ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in text]).strip().split()[0]

val_list = [(normalize(root.xpath('//table[@class="infobox geography vcard"]//tr[./th/text()="Area"]/following-sibling::tr[{}]//text()'.format(str(val)))[1]), normalize(root.xpath('//table[@class="infobox geography vcard"]//tr[./th/text()="Area"]/following-sibling::tr[{}]//text()'.format(str(val)))[3])) for val in xrange(1,4)]
print(val_list)
```

The above code will output :

```
[(u'Total', u'17.6'), (u'Land', u'17.6'), (u'Water', u'0.0')]
```